# Run time error 91-Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: function, excel, vba

```
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Sub findfilmnameusingeventhandler()

Sheet1.Activate

Dim searchrange As Range
Dim filmname As String
Dim releasedate As Integer
Dim filmtofind As String

Set searchrange = Range("b3", Range("b2").End(xlDown))
filmname = InputBox("Type the movie")
filmtofind = searchrange.Find(what:=filmname)

'filmtofind = Range("b2:b15").Find(what:=filmname)

MsgBox filmtofind & "  is the movie "

End Sub`
```

Hi, Thank you for reviewing my question. I've declared a range variable & use it to search a string "filmtofind = searchrange.Find(what:=filmname)" & it fails with run time error 
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
however I can search for same range with a declared range 
filmtofind = Range("b2:b15").Find(what:=filmname) & can find a variable. COuld someone please point the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The film you are entering does not exist in the list, try an error check like this:

```
Sub something()

Dim searchrange As Range
Dim filmname As String
Dim releasedate As Integer
Dim filmtofind As String

Set searchrange = Range("B3", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
filmname = InputBox("Type the movie")
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(searchrange, filmname) > 0 Then
    filmtofind = searchrange.Find(what:=filmname)
Else
    filmtofind = "Film not found!"
End If

'filmtofind = Range("b2:b15").Find(what:=filmname)

MsgBox filmtofind & "  is the movie "

End Sub
```